# save the output in a matrix or array in C programming

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, save, output

I have a C programming code, I am so basic at C and want to save the output in an array or matrix. In python one can easy append the output in a empty array.

now, I saved my output directly in a .csv file
I am not able to share all my code, but I save the output in a csv file like this:

```
int main()
{
    int N_iter = 2000;
    int i;

    FILE *fptr;
            fptr = fopen("data.csv", "a"); // "a" defines "writing and appending mode"
    for(i = 0; i < N_iter; i++){

       .
       .
       .
       /* printing the output to see what's happening */
        printf("i = [%d] | a = %f | b = %f | c = %f \n", k, (float)a , (float)b,(float)c);

    
       /* write to csv file */
        fprintf(fptr, "%d ,%f ,%f ,%f \n", k, (float)a , (float)b, (float)c);

    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

now, I need to save the output (k, a, b, c) which is a 2000*4 dimension array in a array or matrix beacuse I think this method is faster than opening a csv file and write the output in it. How can I do that?

Comment: Create an array of the right size with `malloc()` and store the data in it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you come across structures yet?  If so, you should use an array of structures.  If not, you may have to use 4 arrays — one of type `int` for the `k` values, another for the `a` values, another for the `b` values, and another for the `c` values (of type `float` or `double`).  Your `(float)a` casts in the calls to `printf()` are puzzling.  The compiler will convert what's in `a` to a `float` because of the cast, but then converts that to `double` because of the default argument promotion rules that apply to variadic functions such as `printf()`.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ You don't show the declarations for `a`, `b` or `c`; presumably they're `double` rather `int`, but why throw away accuracy with the cast to `float`?  If it were my code, there'd be no spaces before the commas or the newlines in the print formats.  I would probably not put a space after the commas in the CSV notation either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I dont know what you are saying. I am so basic. please write the code for me. I want a matrix 2000*4 at the output

Comment: No — I will not write the code for you.  That's not what SO is about.  We will help you fix problems in an honest attempt to solve the problem, but we cannot gauge your level of expertise if you don't show your code, and we will give inappropriate answers using concepts you aren't familiar with.  If you don't know how to create 4 arrays and copy values into them, you need to go back to the lessons where they were taught and redo the reading and the practice.  If you don't know how to do dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()`, use fixed size arrays instead.  If you know structures, use them.

Comment: To my way of thinking, the casts in the calls to `printf()` should be superfluous.  Casts should be avoided when possible, and it often is possible to avoid them.  They are the last resort; your code should usually not need them.  I'm fussy about the data that's generated by my programs.  Trailing blanks are anathema to me.  You can ignore my suggestions there, but I regard trailing blanks as unprofessional, and I'm chagrined when any of my code produces them.

Comment: Also, people are more willing to help when you present an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — the same idea by a different name.  Note that an MCVE requires sample input data, required output data, actual output data (if the program runs) as well as the (minimal) code that you need help with.  Often, the process of creating an MCVE resolves the problem you're having.  When it doesn't, you have the basis for a question on SO.